# UWP: Binding GridView to large collection cause ComboBox to lock the UI

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp, template10

I have a somewhat large dataset that I bind to a GridView. It's not *that* large, just 880 items. It takes a while for the app to display the items, but they get there after a couple of seconds.

However, if I load the complete dataset (880 "devices") any ComboBox will lock the UI. And I do mean *any* ComboBox, even the ones without any items and the ones not databound, just clean ComboBox.

If I load just a subset of the items (say 200), the ComboBoxes work fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an error?

Comment: Are you not virtualizing your items or template recycling? Would likely need more info.

Comment: I don't even know what that means. I load data from a server using JSON, and placing the items in an ObservableCollection.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization) will put you on track to improve your performance significantly.

Comment: Ah, very nice! Thanks! :)